# How to fix Firebase Cloud Functions Cors Error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I got on my project at least 12 cloud functions on which most of them are `onRequest` ones and they work perfectly. However, I just created a new one that I'm getting cors errors. Tried a bunch of things and it doesn't work.

This is what I have:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

export const trkFun = functions.https.onRequest(
    async (request, response) => {
      const trackingNumber = request.body.trackingNumber;
      
      const responseBody = await fetch(endPoint);
      const res = await responseBody.json();
      response.send(res.objetos);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may be aware cors is used to enable cross origin resource sharing. I'm assuming your error is coming from trying to trigger to `OnRequest` from other origins.

You can do the following just below your imports:

```
const cors = require('cors')({
  origin: true //this will allow all origins, you can limit to to a particular domain etc. but this is a good option for a public api.
});
```

Then try the following:

```
export trkFun = functions.https.onRequest(
    async (request, response) => {
        cors(request, response, async () => {
         //... do your things in here
       }
  });
```